# image resizing & Dragging inside a canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, draggable

I've been trying to drag and resize the same image inside my canvas but i am not able to successfully do that

I've selected the dragging codes from the first link and resizing codes from the second link but while combining those codes the final output  has some errors and issues. I have also added an upload image button in which the user can choose the image to be uploaded to the canvas from a local directory, that was working properly

```js
$(function () {
    $('#file-input').change(function (e) {
        var file = e.target.files[0],
            imageType = /image.*/;
        if (!file.type.match(imageType))
            return;
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = fileOnload;
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
    function fileOnload(e) {
        var $img = $('<img>', { src: e.target.result });
        var canvas = $('#canvas')[0];
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        $img.load(function () {
            context.drawImage(this, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            fileResize();
        });
    }
    function fileResize() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var canvasOffset = $("#canvas").offset();
        var offsetX = canvasOffset.left;
        var offsetY = canvasOffset.top;
        var startX;
        var startY;
        var isDown = false;
       //  var pi2 = Math.PI * 2;  
        var resizerRadius = 10;
        var rr = resizerRadius * resizerRadius ;
        var imageX = 0;
        var imageY = 0;
        var imageWidth, imageHeight, imageRight, imageBottom;
        var draggingImage = false;
        var img = new Image();

        var draggingResizer = {
            x: 0,
            y: 0
        };

        img.onload = function () {
            imageWidth = img.width;
            imageHeight = img.height;
            imageRight = imageX + imageWidth;
            imageBottom = imageY + imageHeight;
            iOrientation = (imageWidth >= imageHeight) ? "Wide" : "Tall";
            draw(true, true);
        }
        img.src = canvas.toDataURL();

    var border = 8;
    var isLeft = false;
    var isRight = false;
    var isTop = false;
    var isBottom = false;
    var iAnchor;

    canvas.onmousedown = handleMousedown;
    canvas.onmousemove = handleMousemove;
    canvas.onmouseup = handleMouseup;
    canvas.onmouseout = handleMouseup;


function draw(withAnchors, withBorders) {
        var cx = imageX + (imageRight - imageX) / 2;
        var cy = imageY + (imageBottom - imageY) / 2;
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.drawImage(img, imageX, imageY, imageRight - imageX, imageBottom - imageY);
        ctx.setLineDash([10, 15]);
            ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";
            ctx.stroke();

    if (withAnchors) {
        ctx.fillRect(imageX, imageY, border, border);
        ctx.fillRect(imageRight - border, imageY, border, border);
        ctx.fillRect(imageRight - border, imageBottom - border, border, border);
        ctx.fillRect(imageX, imageBottom - border, border, border);
        ctx.fillRect(cx, imageY, border, border);
        ctx.fillRect(cx, imageBottom - border, border, border);
        ctx.fillRect(imageX, cy, border, border);
        ctx.fillRect(imageRight - border, cy, border, border);
            
        }
        if (withBorders) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(imageX, imageY);
            ctx.lineTo(imageRight, imageY);
            ctx.lineTo(imageRight, imageBottom);
            ctx.lineTo(imageX, imageBottom);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.stroke();
        }}

function hitResizeAnchor(x, y) {

    // which borders are under the mouse
    isLeft = (x > imageX && x < imageX + border);
    isRight = (x < imageRight && x > imageRight - border);
    isTop = (y > imageY && y < imageY + border);
    isBottom = (y < imageBottom && y > imageBottom - border);

    // return the appropriate anchor
    if (isTop && isLeft) {
        return (iOrientation + "TL");
    }
    if (isTop && isRight) {
        return (iOrientation + "TR");
    }
    if (isBottom && isLeft) {
        return (iOrientation + "BL");
    }
    if (isBottom && isRight) {
        return (iOrientation + "BR");
    }
    if (isTop) {
        return ("T");
    }
    if (isRight) {
        return ("R");
    }
    if (isBottom) {
        return ("B");
    }
    if (isLeft) {
        return ("L");
    }
    return ("null");
}

var resizeFunctions = {

    T: function (x, y) {
        imageY = y;
        canvas.style.cursor = "n-resize";
    },
    R: function (x, y) {
        imageRight = x;
    },
    B: function (x, y) {
        imageBottom = y;
    },
    L: function (x, y) {
        imageX = x;
    },

    WideTR: function (x, y) {
        imageRight = x;
        imageY = imageBottom - (imageHeight * (imageRight - imageX) / imageWidth);
    },
    TallTR: function (x, y) {
        imageY = y;
        imageRight = imageX + (imageWidth * (imageBottom - imageY) / imageHeight);
    },
    WideBR: function (x, y) {
        imageRight = x;
        imageBottom = imageY + (imageHeight * (imageRight - imageX) / imageWidth);
    },
    TallBR: function (x, y) {
        imageBottom = y;
        imageRight = imageX + (imageWidth * (imageBottom - imageY) / imageHeight);
    },

    WideBL: function (x, y) {
        imageX = x;
        imageBottom = imageY + (imageHeight * (imageRight - imageX) / imageWidth);
    },
    TallBL: function (x, y) {
        imageBottom = y;
        imageX = imageRight - (imageWidth * (imageBottom - imageY) / imageHeight);
    },

    WideTL: function (x, y) {
        imageX = x;
        imageY = imageBottom - (imageHeight * (imageRight - imageX) / imageWidth);
    },
    TallTL: function (x, y) {
        imageBottom = y;
        imageX = imageRight - (imageWidth * (imageBottom - imageY) / imageHeight);
    }
};


function hitImage(x, y) {
    return (x > imageX && x < imageX + imageWidth && y > imageY && y < imageY + imageHeight);
}

function handleMousedown(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    canvas.style.cursor = "move";
    startX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
    startY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
    var mouseX = e.clientX - offsetX;
    var mouseY = e.clientY - offsetY;
    iAnchor = hitResizeAnchor(mouseX, mouseY);   
    isDown = (iAnchor); 
    draggingImage = hitImage(startX, startY);
}

function handleMouseup(e) {
    canvas.style.cursor = "default";
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    draggingImage = false;
    isDown = false;
    draw(true);
}

function handleMousemove(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (isDown) {       
         var mouseX = e.clientX - offsetX;
        var mouseY = e.clientY - offsetY;
        resizeFunctions[iAnchor](mouseX, mouseY);
        draw(false);
        }
    if (draggingImage) {
                canvas.style.cursor = "move";
                imageClick = false;
                mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
                mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
                var dx = mouseX - startX;                       
                var dy = mouseY - startY;
                imageX += dx;
                imageY += dy;
                imageRight += dx;
                imageBottom += dy;
                startX = mouseX;                        
                startY = mouseY;
                draw(false, true);    
    }
}
function handleMouseOut(e) {
    handleMouseUp(e);
}

    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>  
<head>
    <title>Upload to Canvas</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="demo-uploader.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <input type="file" id="file-input" accept=".jpg,.png,.gif.,svg">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="400" style="  border: solid thin #232323;"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```